# iOS If Else Statement- Rotating Views

Tags: ios, error-handling, rotation, boolean

I have views in my view controller that become hidden and shown. I want to force the orientation of these views. Here is the code I have but I receive a error and I am not sure why.

Thanks in Advance for the help

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (contentview.hidden = TRUE); {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } 
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way:

```
if (contentview.hidden == YES) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace single `=` with comparison operator `==`  And also remove `;` after if condition

```
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
    if (contentview.hidden == TRUE) {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } 
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ';' character. If-statements don't require them.